# java.lang.InstantiationException while mapping abstract class using jaxb

Tags: inheritance, jaxb, xsitype

I am following the blog post :
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

and I have done all the same things, except that my subclasses are not public and are in the same file as that of the abstract class file. I get java.lang.InstantiationException exception 
    javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of     org.apache.ambari.server.state.DependencyConditionInfo
     - with linked exception:
    [java.lang.InstantiationException]
        at     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(    UnmarshallingContext.java:647)

**EDIT**

When I use @XmlSeeAlso I need to provide a default constructor, due to which I am not able to initialize the data member of the subclass.

Can anyone help me find a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why this is failing is because Jaxb will attempt to create an instance of User. which is abstract and therefore the failure.

On your abstract class add the annotations

```
@XmlTransient //Prevents the mapping of a JavaBean property/type to XML representation
@XmlSeeAlso({Admin.class, <other class>}) //Instructs JAXB to also bind other classes when binding this class
```

see the javadoc for each([XmlTransient](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.5/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html), [XmlSeeAlso](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.5/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html))

What this will do is prevent jaxb from trying to initialize your abstract class.

The only downside to this method I found is there will be extra namespace information added to the xml that gets created.

*Solved by @wyche5000*

Comment: Hi Luca, thanks, that exception went after adding @XmlSeeAlso, but this tag expects a default constructor for the subclasses. If I add default constructor I get a NullPointerException as the parameters of the subclasses go uninitialized. Could you give some pointers?